# How do I use the "#using" statement in c++?

Tags: visual-c++, using

I'm trying to use the isKeyLocked function, but according to Microsoft's C++ example, I need to use `#using <System.Windows.Forms.dll>`. If I do this, my program throws a compile time error.

[Here's the source of the example.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.iskeylocked.aspx#Y342)

Comment: Which compiler are you using?

Comment: That method is .Net and you need to be using managed C++.

Comment: Assuming you didn't actually meant to write C++/CLI code, consider using GetKeyState() to accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

You should compile in Managed C++ mode.

Go to `Project Properties`, `General` and set `Common Language Runtime support` to `/clr`,
or from command line,

```
cl.exe main.cpp /clr
```